# Pulling data from parse.com but it is not displaying at all in the UITableView in ios (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I am pulling an array of object from parse.com using a query. I have NsLog statements that show that I am correctly retrieving data from parse but when I try and iterate over these objects and put information into an array that my tableview uses as it source, nothing shows up. Here is my code:

```
class FunListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var funlists = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var query = PFQuery(className: "FunLists")
    query.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")

            // Do something with the found objects
            for object in objects {
                NSLog("%@", object.objectId)
                self.funlists.append(object.objectId)
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  self.funlists.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = self.funlists[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are done updating the data source, you have to explicitly tell the table to reload.

Since data is provided inside a closure, and most likely in a different thread than the main, this is what you should add after the for loop:

```
    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")

        // Do something with the found objects
        for object in objects {
            NSLog("%@", object.objectId)
            self.funlists.append(object.objectId)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        ...
```